# How can I convert the PHP Array to JSON Array?

Tags: json

I have an Array as below.

```
[
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    },
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    },
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    }
]
```

How can I convert this to

```
{
"Title":
[
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    },
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    },
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    }
]
}
```

In PHP.

Comment: Both are JSON.  The only difference is the bottom is an object where the top structure is assigned to the 'title' key.

Comment: Short answer: de-serialise it, manipulate it like any other PHP variable until  it has the structure you want, and then serialise it again.

Answer (score 2):

Simply convert the JSON String to a PHP data type, adding the new `title` property and then use `json_encode()` to recreate the JSON String

```
<?php
$json = '[
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    },
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    },
    {
        "imageUrl": "url",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "href": "#"
    }
]';
$new['title'] = json_decode($json);
$new_json = json_encode( $new );
echo $new_json;
```

RESULT

```
{"title":[
            {"imageUrl":"url","Text":"Lorem ipsum","href":"#"},
            {"imageUrl":"url","Text":"Lorem ipsum","href":"#"},
            {"imageUrl":"url","Text":"Lorem ipsum","href":"#"}
        ]   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is an array:

```
$output = ['title' => $input];
```

If the input is a string:

```
$output = '{ "Title": ' . $input . '}';
```

Comment: What is this even answering? Also, `json_encode` exists for a reason. As pointed out by @Devon '*The only difference is the bottom is an object where the top structure is assigned to the 'title' key.*'.

Comment: @Script47 : isn't that exactly what I'm doing? OP didn't say anything about JSON encode/decode, just that they want to convert 1 object to another.

Comment: Except, it is tagged as `php` and `json`?

Comment: Downvoters: curious what I'm missing. It was an honest attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Script47 so the second sample would convert the first json object to the second. Why use a separate json_encode and json_decode step for this, this will be much faster.

Comment: Because manually constructing JSON string can cause avoidable errors, that's why and as for the the efficiency factor, I'm sure it is negligible.

Comment: Write a unittest? This is an extremely straightforward case. JSON is a fairly simple specification. Regardless, I don't see that that difference in opinion is enough reason for a downvote.

Comment: If you're worried about hand-writing JSON, an extremely minimal almost subset of javascript, you probably shouldn't write any PHP or javascript. It's much more complex and creates an even higher potential for bugs ;)

Comment: That's a clear straw man. You can be an expert in both and still make a mistake somewhere along the way with a stray quote.

Comment: True for any language. You can't know if you made an error until you tested it. A stray quote would be an extremely obvious defect.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would 100% agree with you with any mildly complex case. This is just not one of them. It's self-contained, and logic-free.

Comment: I'd say the main issue with building the JSON by hand would be the unknown quantity in $input - if _that_ contains special characters such as quotes it could screw things up. A proper encoder takes care of all that kind of thing. While _this_ case may be simple, you can see the potential for future readers extrapolating this answer onto more dubious use cases.

Comment: @ADyson, yea you're right. If `$input` is invalid JSON, `$output` will too. If `$input` was valid, so will `$output`.

Comment: '*For what it's worth, I would 100% agree with you with any mildly complex case. This is just not one of them. It's self-contained, and logic-free.*' - That's where I guess we both differed. I was thinking this to be setting a bad precedent for the OP to just build JSON by string in the future. Bad practices creep in quickly but are there to stay in most cases, sadly.

Comment: @Evert Indeed. And because we can't guarantee that $input is valid, that's why we shouldn't ever be building the output by hand like this. That was my point, more or less the same as Script47's. $input could just be a simple string "Mr O'Brien" or something innocuous like that (so not even JSON per-se to start with), and your code would fall over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode` from PHP library.
More information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).